# receive from raw socket failed

Tags: linux, sockets

`enter code here`I am trying to read router solicitation packet from network interface usb0 with inet6 family
I have created raw socket and bind raw socket to USB0 interface
I am trying to read data from interface using loop  as

```
while(1)
{
int len = recvmsg(sockid,&msghdr,0)
if(len < 0)
{perror("received failed");
exit(1);
}
processmessage

}
```

The problem is i am getting error : received failed resources temporarily unavialble

I wonder socket is still exiting ,interface existand bind is successful.what could be the possible reason for error?

Answer (score 1):

If the errno is EAGAIN you could retry the recvmsg for some time and then exit later:

```
int retryCount = 0;
while(1) {
    int len = recvmsg(sockid,&msghdr,0)
    if (len < 0) {
        if ((errno == EAGAIN) && (++retryCount < 128))
            continue;

        perror("received failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    retryCount = 0;
    processmessage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly you should check this file:

cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/usb0/forwarding

make sure or set the value 1:

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/usb0/forwarding

ensure the value of /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/forwarding is 0 while the kernel is no more than 2.6.

good luck!